# How to hide the keyboard by pressing the bar button

Tags: iphone, cocoa

The problem is that the cursor is on one textfield. And I want to press the bar button to hide the keyboard. This bar button used the IB to create and connect with one IBAction.

Comment: then on your ibaction method write [yourtextfield resignfirstresponder];

Comment: @Chinttu Actually, there have many textfields. and these textfield is the subview of cell, which is created custom. So in the tableviewcontroller, I want to press the bar button to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [YourView endEditing:YES];

This will cause any text field in your view to resign the first responder status

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)BarButtonMethod
{
   [yourTextFieldObject resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Just do it and get you o/p

Comment: so how to get this textfield object. This control has many textfields. and textfield is the subview of cell.contentview. So the situation is that tableview -> cell(custom) -> textfield.